# How to avoid extracting resolve from promises, while start a process before a callback?

Tags: javascript, promise, generator

Quite often I'm finding myself using a pattern similar to:

```
const foo = () => {
    const _resolve;
    const promise = new Promise(resolve => _resolve = resolve);
    myAsyncCall(_resolve);
    return (dataWeDontHaveYet) => promise.then(cb => cb(dataWeDontHaveYet));
}
const finalData = async2(foo());

function async2(cb) {
    ... async stuff ...
    return cb(dataWeDidntHaveBefore);
}

function myAsyncCall(cb) { return cb(somePrimitive); }
```

So I have an async call I want to get started right away, but I need to act on the resolve of the async call with data I don't have yet.

Sorta like a queue.

Maybe I shouldn't use promises? I'm not sure. I've used this before, but I can't find the code. Currently I'm trying to convert a stream into a generator and am having a tough time.

EDIT: I created a new question that is very specifically my problem, which can be found at [How to convert a stream into a generator without leaking resolve from a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548731/how-to-convert-a-stream-into-a-generator-without-leaking-resolve-from-a-promise)

Comment: i feel like youre making this way more complicated than it needs to be.. why are you injecting the promise into the function rather than just returning a promise from the function itself...

Comment: Dealing with compression with large files can be challenging, especially when browsers typically don't do it.

FYI I'm using the JSZip library for compression, which at best has a stream like return.

Comment: *stream-like return

Comment: that's not how `const` works.. you need to use `let`

Comment: and as explained below `const myAsyncCall(_resolve);` is invalid code as well.

Comment: Sorry about this. I'm trying to write sample code for a problem I've been running into several times a year for years, but the problem changes every time and I've always managed to avoid it with a large restructuring of my code... but I'm wondering if there is a more basic solution to resolving what I consider to be an anti-pattern.

Give me a moment to ensure the code is entirely valid. Sorry about writing the question too hastily.

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell Maybe it would help to post your actual code where we can see what actual is happening where, so that we can then simplify based on that. It seems like currently your whole code can be simplified to `const finalData = new Promise(resolve => { /* async stuff */ resolve(dataWeDidntHaveBefore); })` - none of all the functions is necessary.

Comment: Ya I'm going to post the actual problem of converting a stream to a generator. I'm have a difficult time coming up with code that causes this anti-pattern, outside of my current issue.

Comment: More accurate, and specific question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548731/how-to-convert-a-stream-into-a-generator-without-leaking-resolve-from-a-promise

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you have up there doesn't really make sense, so hopefully I'm on the right track with this answer.

You'd need to wait on your async data by either using a Promise or a callback as well. You'd just chain them together and return the start of the Promise.

If `myAsyncCall()` also returns a `Promise`, you can just do this:

```
return myAsyncCall();
```

That would return a `Promise` which would resolve once `myAsyncCall()` completes. If you need to transform that data, you can chain any number of `then()` onto it:

```
return myAsyncCall().then(d => transform(d));
```

That would resolve `myAsyncCall()` first, then transform, then subsequent `then()` calls would get whatever the latest called.

If `myAsyncCall()` uses a callback instead, you can have that return a `Promise`:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  myAsyncCall(data => resolve(data));
});
```

This will let `myAsyncCall()` resolve, then pass that data along to a `Promise` which is then used for further things.

---

After your updates, I think I understand a little better what you are looking for. It looks like you're basically just trying to chain together callbacks and Promises.

First, a look at normal "callback" chaining.

```js
const a = (start, cb) => cb(start);
const b = (input, cb) => cb(input + 5);

a(1, result => 
  b(result, newResult => 
    console.log(newResult)
  )
);
```

This is the callback way of chaining. Basically, you pass a function in as a parameter that receives a parameter which is the result of the previous function.

The nested approach is a bit messy, so a lot of people will break it up a bit:

```js
const a = (start, cb) => cb(start);
const b = (input, cb) => cb(input + 5);

const onA = result => b(result, onB);
const onB = result => console.log(result);

a(1, onA);
```

With `Promises` they are chained by using `then()`. The above working with all Promises looks like this:

```js
const a = start => Promise.resolve(start);
const b = input => Promise.resolve(input + 5);

a(1).then(b).then(result => console.log(result));
```

Now, when you need to mix the two, there are a couple of approaches. One would be to just mix them together in a more direct fashion:

```js
const a = start => Promise.resolve(start);
const b = (input, cb) => cb(input + 5);

a(1).then(result => b(result, result => console.log(result)));
```

This works, but leaves you with a lot of the same messiness of nested callbacks.

A cleaner approach is to "promisify" a callback. While there are libraries that will do this for you, a quick `promisify` function looks like this:

```js
const promisify = func => (...args) => new Promise(resolve => {
  const cb = result => resolve(result);
  func.apply(func, args.concat(cb));
});

const a = (start, cb) => cb(start);
const b = (input, cb) => cb(input + 5);

const aPromisified = promisify(a);
const bPromisified = promisify(b);

aPromisified(1)
 .then(bPromisified)
 .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Basically, it just wraps up a callback function into a Promise. This then lets you treat it as a Promise. I use this approach a lot for built-in Node library functions.

If you need a `promisify` that works with the typical Node format for callbacks of `(err, result)`, then you can use this one and pass in `true` for "withErr":

```js
const promisify = (func, withErr = false) => (...args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const handler = (err, result) => {
    if(withErr) {
     err ? reject(err) : resolve(result);
    } else {
     resolve(err);
    }
  }
  
  func.apply(func, args.concat(handler));
});

const aCallback = (start, cb) => cb(start);
const bCallback = (input, cb) => cb(input === 3 && 'cannot be 3', input + 5);

const a = promisify(aCallback);
const b = promisify(bCallback, true);

a(1).then(b).then(r => console.log(r));
a(3).then(b).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Those are three unrelated lines of code. Can you rewrite what I wrote using your methodology. It looks to me like your solution is too simple.

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell "too simple" lol what? does your project have a minimum complexity standard?

Comment: I would, but I don't understand what you wrote. The syntax isn't valid. You can't call a `Promise` like a function (`promise(dataWeDoNotYetHave`) and you can't have `const myAsyncCall(_resolve)`. I suspect what you are doing isn't actually as complicated as you think, you just need to be chaining things properly.

Comment: Very possible! I'm trying to untangle the callbacks so I can chain things without leaking a resolve.

I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: FYi, to give you an idea. I'm trying to convert a stream into a generator, and I've already converted a file blob slicer into a generator. This isn't my first rodeo.

Comment: I'm still not 100% positive as to what you're trying to do, since the code still doesn't quite make sense, but I'm going to update my answer with how you can chain things together. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to write a new question with the exact problem.

Sorry for the poorly organized question.

Comment: Updated my post with the various ways to mix and match callback and promises.

Comment: Specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548731/how-to-convert-a-stream-into-a-generator-without-leaking-resolve-from-a-promise

Meanwhile I'll take a look at what you wrote to see if I can find a nice solution.

Comment: Nice list of tricks. Unfortunately none solve my generator problem. I'll try and remember this QA for the next time I want to leak the resolve and perhaps one of these well solve that problem :).