# How to convert a stream into a generator without leaking resolve from a promise

Tags: javascript, generator

I have a stream and I need to convert it to a generator, so an uploader can consume the generic generator.

This means turning:

```
stream.on('data', chunk => ...);
```

to:

```
generator = streamGenerator(stream);
chunk = await generator.next()
...
```

better yet:

```
chunk = yield streamGenerator;
```

Overall my best attempt requires leaking the resolve from a promise and I'd like to avoid that:

```
function streamToIterable(chunkSize, stream) {
    let collector = [];
    let value = [];
    let done = false;
    let _resolve;
    let promise = new Promise(resolve => _resolve = resolve);
    stream.on('data', chunk => {
        collector = collector.concat(chunk);
        if (value.length >= chunkSize) {
            value = collector.splice(0, chunkSize);
            _resolve(value);
            stream.pause();
        }
    });
    stream.on('end', () => {
        _resolve(collection);

        // With done set to true, the next iteration well ignore 'value' and end the loop
        done = true;
    });
    stream.resume();

    return {
        next: () => ({
            value: promise.then(() => {
                stream.resume();
                promise = new Promise(resolve => _resolve = resolve);
            }),
            done,
        }),
    };
}

function* streamToGenerator(stream) {
    const iterator = streamToIterable(stream);
    let next = iterator.next();
    while (!next.done) {
        yield next.value;
    }
};
```

Usage in a generator for uploading chunks:

```
for (const chunkData of generator()) {
    let result = yield uploadPost(url, formData, onChunkProgress(chunkIndex));
```

This is in a redux-saga, so "next()" isn't called on the generator until the return promise is resolved.

Comment: What should happen if the stream isn't complete, but has nothing ready yet, so `next()` may not have a chunk ready to give it? Should it give it an empty string as a chunk so it'll keep trying, or give `null`, which would (generally) end it?

Comment: "promise" won't resolve, so "value" won't resolve yet.

I should add that I plan to use this generator in another generator using a while loop and yield. I'll add that info to the question, thank you.

Comment: I added the use case. It was copy pasted from my code.

Comment: Btw, `streamToGenerator` is pretty useless. Both `streamToGenerator` and `streamToIterable` do return an iterator. (And given that you don't handle `throw` and `return`, there's no advantage in a generator).

Comment: Except that if a library like redux-sagas checks the prototype of the iterator function, it won't match a generator.

Comment: Wanted to add that concat doesn't behave the way you think it does here.  Concat returns a new array which you assign something else to it for reference, otherwise it is lost.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I simply forgot to assign it. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot avoid storing the `resolve` function in a mutable variable if you want to use a single event listener that resolves different promises. You *could* simplify the promise creation by using the [`once` method](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_eventname_listener) similar to the following:

```
function streamToIterator(stream) {
    let done = false;
    const end = new Promise(resolve => {
        stream.once('end', resolve);
    }).then(e => {
        done = true;
    });

    return {
        [Symbol.iterator]() { return this; }
        next() {
            const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
                stream.once('data', value => {
                    resolve(value);
                    stream.pause();
                });
                stream.resume();
            });

            return {
                value: Promise.race([promise, end]),
                done,
            };
        }),
    };
}
```

Of course, you are doing the racing between `end` and `data` yourself, you resume the stream before `next` is called the first time and most importantly you do the chunking yourself, so this might to be applicable to your situation.

Apart from that, I'd recommend to check out the [buffering internals of node.js streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_buffering), it might be easier to read chunks of certain sizes using a lower-level API than `data` events.

Also you definitely should have a look at the [asynchronous iteration proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration) for es-next. The iterable interface you're trying to implement is very similar, and surely they either already have or really would welcome an example of making a node readablestream iterable.

Comment: My friend JUST showed me that proposal 2 days ago. Also I realized on ym walk home that the jsZip stream not having "once" implemented was the first problem.

I'll implement a helper function to have a "once" for the stream.

Thanks for all the additional peice of information.

Comment: Doesn't `jsZip` return a node [`Readable` stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) that implements [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)?

Comment: Not when you're in the browser. That's why they added a "StreamHelper" so there was some kind of way to consume the zip peice by peice outside of node.

Comment: Oh, I had kinda assumed you would use this on the server side.

Comment: Ya sorry, again, I should have specified I was doing this for the browser, considering no one would expect, let alone, assume someone is doing this in the browser.

Comment: What happens if you call next() twice before you get a data stream?

You'll return the first set of data twice and your offset well be incorrect.

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell Yes, you are not supposed to do that :-) `for await` won't do it, but if you want to guard against it you will need to build a promise queue for all `next` calls (like async generator functions do it).

Comment: I was just about to ask if that proposal would apply to this situation and then I read the last paragraph. Very thorough, +1

Comment: I wish I could mark both answers as correct.

I marked yours as correct and I'll remove the mention of JSZip, because it's volitility is what caused me to require a more robust solution than the one you provided. It seems other have noticed this question and your answer well answer their question more than mine well.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this answer is only required if you have a volatile stream that doesn't pause right away, and therefor also doesn't have an event system that supports "once". It also allows asyncronous yielding.

I greatly changed my previous answer and this one works.

This one uses two arrays; one of promises and another of resolves, which allows a queue of data that is bi-directional.

So if you iterate faster than the stream, all promises well resolve when they receive data and also if you stream faster than you iterate, you'll have promises to resolve from the iterator.

```
function streamToAsyncIterator(chunkSize, stream) {
    let done = false;
    let endPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
        //flush out the last data.
        stream.on('end', () => {
            resolve({ value: collector, done: false });
        });
    });

    //two-track queue for expecting and sending data with promises
    let dataPromises = [];
    let dataResolves = [];
    stream.on('data', value => {
        const dataResolve = dataResolves.shift();
        if (dataResolve) {
            dataResolve({ value, done: false });
        } else {
            dataPromises.push(Promise.resolve({ value, done: false }));
        }
        stream.pause();
    });

    return {
        [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
            return this;
        },
        //TODO handle return() to close the stream
        next() {
            if (done) return Promise.resolve({ done });

            stream.resume();

            let dataPromise = dataPromises.shift();
            if (!dataPromise) {
                dataPromise = new Promise(resolve => dataResolves.push(resolve));
            }

            return Promise.race([dataPromise, endPromise])
                // done must be set in the resolution of the race, or done could complete the generator before the last iteration of data.
                .then(next => {
                     if (next.done) {
                         done = true;
                         next.done = false;
                     }
                     return next;
                });
        },
    };
}

async function* streamToAsyncGenerator(chunkSize, stream) {
    const iterator = streamToAsyncIterator(chunkSize, stream);
    let next = await iterator.next();
    while (!next.done) {
        yield next.value;
        // Delete is needed to release resouces
        // Without delete, you'll get a memory error at 2GB.
        delete next.value;
        next = await iterator.next();
    }
};
```

EDIT: I removed the collector, which has nothing to do with the question and I added the delete which is necessary, because GC doesn't appear to run with an array of iterators. This should be the final answer as it works swell for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate directly over the stream using `for await (const chunk of stream)`

```js
const streamGenerator = async function* () {
  const stream = new Readable({
    read() {
      this.push('a');
      this.push('b');
      this.push('c');
      this.push(null);
    },
  });

  for await (const chunk of stream) {
    yield chunk;
  }
}
let result = Buffer.alloc(0);
for await (const chunk of streamGenerator()) {
  result = Buffer.concat([result, chunk]);
}
expect(result).toEqual(Buffer.from('abc'));
```

---

Bonus answer! Going the other way is just as easy:

```js
const streamGenerator = async function* () {
  yield 'a';
  yield 'b';
  yield 'c';
}
const stream = Readable.from(streamGenerator());
let result = Buffer.alloc(0);
for await (const chunk of stream) {
  result = Buffer.concat([result, Buffer.from(chunk)]);
}
expect(result).toEqual(Buffer.from('abc'));
```